# If $D$ is nef, then $h^1(D)=h^2(D)=0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, sheaf-cohomology, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a number field and $S$ a smooth algebraic surface over $k$ which is birational to $\Bbb{P}^2_k$.

I'm trying to understand why the following is true:

> If $D$ is nef divisor on $S$, then $h^1(S,\mathcal{O}_S(D))=h^2(S,\mathcal{O}_S(D))=0$.

[I've read this claim in the the lecutre notes of a course on arithmetic geometry]

Apparently this is supposed to be a trivial statement, but I can't prove it.

The only tools I know how to use here is Riemann-Roch for surfaces or Serre duality. But I don't what to do about $\chi(S,\mathcal{O}_S)$ and $\mathcal{O}_S(K_S-D)$.

I also keep wondering whether or not if $k$ being a number field and $S$ being birational to $\Bbb{P}^2_k$ are necessary in order to conclude that $h^1(D)=h^2(D)=0$.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: As you've noted, by Serre Duality we have $h^2(D) = h^0(K_S - D)$. The second quantity is $0$ since $h^0(K_S-D) \le h^0(K_S) = 0$, and the vanishing is because 1) it vanishes for $S = \mathbb P^2$, and 2) it's a general fact that the numbers $h^0(mK_S)$ (the **plurigenera**) are birational invariants. It's not immediately obvious to me how to get $h^1(D)=0$; based on the given data, I would assume that RR for surfaces might come into play since the hypothesis (nefness) is intersection-theoretic, but showing higher cohomology vanishing via $\chi(D) = h^0(D)$ seems totally backwards.

Comment: @TabesBridges, why is it that $h^0(K_S-D)\leq h^0(K_S)$? I would agree if $D$ was effective. But being just nef, I can't explain why